# WSO2 API manager gateway cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have the wso2 api manager gateway setup on 5 servers which are clustered. However with clustering enabled the response times for a request to the API manager is about a second slower. What is the advantage of clustering the gateways over just running them normally? I use SVN to sync the gateways so new API are picked up through SVN so I was wondering if there are other advantages to clustering.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main usages of gateway clustering.

1. When you have svn based dep-sync, once an artifact is deployed in
   gateway manager, it sends cluster messages to gateway worker nodes
   so that worker nodes can pull new artifact from svn.
2. If you have enabled gateway cache, when revoking an access token,
   gateway cache should be cleared in all gateway worker nodes. This
   message is passed to all gateway worker nodes as a cluster message.

However, it's strange that you seeing a slowness due to clustering, because when serving requests, clustering is not used. Try enabling either gateway key cache or key manager cache. It will give some performance gain.